# SQL Server stored procedure convert varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure which need to run IN statement. I want to know a way to convert a string (list of comma separated integers) to int. In this example, `positionID` needs to be converted. Please help. Thanks

Here is my stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCount]
    @year varchar(50),
    @positionID varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

Select
    ApplicantID, [Name], PositionID, COUNT(*) AS Votes
                       FROM          dbo.vwLog
                       WHERE Year = @year And PositionID in (@positionID)
                       GROUP BY ApplicantID, [Name], PositionID
                        Order By PositionID, Votes DESC
END
```

Comment: Not possible without using dynamic sql - which gets ugly fast. if you were on MySQL, I'd suggest using its `find_in_set()` function, which would work perfectly for this. But SQL server will insert the full csv string into that "in" and treat it as a single enity, not a series of different numbers as if you HAD written `... IN (1,2,3,...)`

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449183/error-using-csv-string-with-in-operator)

Comment: just use one of the million 'split comma delimited string' functions that returns a TVF and jointhe TVF output

Comment: Where are you calling your SP from? Is it from a .net application?

Comment: @Marc B You can select through it using table vars.  This doesn't require dynamic SQL but to be fair to your point it is easier to setup outside of SQL too.  Though you could write a UDF to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that SQL Server 2008 now supports table types. You can define a table type and on the .net side construct a `DataTable` and pass that as a parameter to your stored procedure. On the SP side that parameter is of type [whatever tabletype you made] Here is an example.

```
TotalPositions = [Some List] //of CSV List
DataTable Positions = new DataTable(); //Create the Datatype
Positions.Columns.Add("PositionID", typeof(int)); //
foreach (string sPos in TotalPositions.Split(','))
Positions.Rows.Add(int.Parse(sPos));
```

You can then Append Positions as a parameter for your stored procedure

```
SqlParameter Param = new SqlParameter();
Param.Value = Positions
Param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
Param.ParameterName = @Positions                    
command.Parameters.Add(Param);
```

In your database you have to define a table type as

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Positions] AS TABLE(
    [Position] int NULL,
)
GO
```

and in your stored procedure add

```
@MyPositions Positions Readonly
```

Now you can treat `@MyPositions` as a table in your procedure and compare to it.

Comment: sure i have another machine with 2008. i can try to run on it if i can get a solution :)

Comment: Yeah Shredder I realized that a moment ago lol.  Now i can edit it into an answer though :))

Answer (score 2):

Does the list you pass in have to be comma-separated? XML will work for 2005 and beyond:

```
DECLARE @productIds xml
SET @productIds ='<Positions><id>3</id><id>6</id><id>15</id></Positions>' 

DECLARE @Positions TABLE (ID int) 

INSERT INTO @Positions (ID) SELECT ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @productIds.nodes('/Positions/id') as ParamValues(ID) 


SELECT * FROM 
    dbo.vwLog L
INNER JOIN 
     @Positions p
ON    p.ID = L.PositionID
```

Answer (score 0):

See [SQL Server Split](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)

And combine that with [CAST/CONVERT](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/07/sql-server-convert-text-to-numbers-integer-cast-and-convert/)