# Get .NET Type from SQL ColumnType

Tags: c#, sql, .net, types, converters

I am workin on something like a "SQL Query generator".
To be able to biuld `WHERE` clauses I need to find out which type the value has in the database.

i.e: if the value is an int I will use operators like (<,>,=), on DateTime I want to add <,>,= and a combobox where the user can select sth like "DateTime.Now".

So thats why I need to differ between the types.

Is there any way to get the Types from the columns of a table converted to a .NET Type ?

I currently got this code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MonitoringContext.Instance.ConnectionString))
{
   conn.Open();
   string query = $"SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{SelectedDatabaseItem}' AND COLUMN_NAME = '{Criteria[currentIndex].ColumnValueComboBox.SelectedItem}'";
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
   object reader = command.ExecuteScalar();
   valueType = Type.GetType(reader.ToString());                    
}

if(valueType != null)
    {
     if (valueType == typeof(DateTime))
     {
         List<string> operators = new List<string>() { "<", ">", "=" };
         Criteria[currentIndex].OperatorValueComboBox.ItemsSource = operators;
         //Add datePicker
         return;
     }
     if(valueType == typeof(int))
     {
          //Add textbox to criteria selector
          return;
     }                    
}
```

So assuming the type in the DB is `int` this is working fine 'cause `Type.GetType("int")` will return `typeof(int)`:

But as soon as it's for example "nvarchar" I cannot convert it to string.

Is there any builtin function to convert this ?

Comment: You will have to do it manually, will not be a big thing since the amount of types is very limited

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen okay so I get the Types as string from the Database and then check if (varchar => string, int => int, => dateTime => dateTime) ?

Comment: Yep, just build a dictionary for the mapping and you can easily handle it

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thank that dict sounds like a nice idea !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "*SQL Server data type* -> *.NET data type*" mapping table built-in; thus, you'll have to do the mapping yourself.

Since the number of data types is restricted (and the number of data types *actually* in use by your app might be even more restriced), this should not be too hard. From an implementation point-of-view, this could be done with a huge `switch` statement or a dictionary.

The mapping itself is documented here:

- [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

A mapping in C# can be found here:

- [SQL Server to .Net type conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8838703/87698)

A word of caution: Note that there might not even be an *exact* correspondence between SQL Server data types and .NET data types: For example, a `decimal(4,2)` has a much shorter range than .net's `Decimal`. The same is true for `datetime` (years 1753-9999 in SQL, 0001-9999 in .NET) and propbably others as well.