# How can I generate random variables according to data types?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, random

I have some databases and tables. I am trying to detect data types of each column and create random variables according to data type?

---

For example:

```
col1 : int
col2 : nvarchar(max)
col3 : bit
```

I need to detect each of the data types in code and create random variables for insert.

Should I create a methods, which check all data types and generate variables, for this work? like:

```
if(datatype.Equals("int"))
   random.Next();
else if(datatype.Equals("string"))
   ...
```

Is there any easy way?

---

Comment: I am using MSSQL.

Comment: also, what is your definition of "random" ? Maybe for int it could be "obvious" (e.g., uniform distribution on all possible values), but for a string you might want to restrict and define a bit more. Should you first determine a random length, then random characters ? which random characters ,do you restrict yourself to letters ? to all unicode characters ? GUID ?

Comment: I made some search and I guess I need to determine characters and length. This is right. But I just try to understand is there any easy way to do that. The solution must be work for string, int, bit, datetime, etc... If no then I guess I have to create my own algorithms one by one for all data types.

Comment: There is no general way of doing this. While you can obviously generate some random bit patterns, and then reinterpret them as an instance of some type (although this is not that easy to do in .NET!) not all bit patterns are valid for all types. This alone is sufficient argument to show why you need special casing, aside from all the other obvious problems with completely random data (namely, that it won't be representative of actual data your application will process). There are various third-party solutions for generating dummy data, but this comment is too narrow to contain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
var random = new Random();
var factory = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>()
{
    { typeof(int), () => random.Next() },
    { typeof(string), () =>
        {
            var bytes = new byte[16];
            random.NextBytes(bytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
    },
    { typeof(DateTime), () => DateTime.Now.AddDays((random.NextDouble() - 0.5) * 100) },
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
var datatype = typeof(string);
var output = factory[datatype]();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

I get `eyqQ1EdMDTsR8Ny8kS73Hg==` as an example output.

You just need to keep building up all of the types you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "SQL Server data type -> .NET data type" mapping table built-in; thus, you'll have to do the mapping yourself.

You can check [SQL Server to .Net type conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838703/sql-server-to-net-type-conversions)

Answer (score 0):

The Random class provides `Random.Next()`, `Random.NextBytes()`, and `Random.NextDouble()` methods. The Random.Next() method returns a random number, `Random.NextBytes()` returns an array of bytes filled with random numbers, and `Random.NextDouble()` returns a random number between 0.0 and 1.0.

The Random.Next() method has three overloaded forms and allows you to set the minimum and maximum range of the random number.

The following code returns a random number.

```
int num = random.Next();
```

The following code returns a random number less than 1000.

```
int num = random.Next(1000);
```

The following code returns a random number between the min and the max range. To Generate a random number between two numbers

```
public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)  
{  
    Random random = new Random();  
    return random.Next(min, max);  
}
```

You can even combine the two methods - RandomNumber and RandomString to generate a combination of random string and numbers.

```
// Generate a random string with a given size  
public string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)  
{  
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
    Random random = new Random();  
    char ch;  
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  
    {  
        ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));  
        builder.Append(ch);  
    }  
    if (lowerCase)  
        return builder.ToString().ToLower();  
    return builder.ToString();  
}
```

[**Reference**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generating-random-number-and-string-in-C-Sharp/)

To know the mapping follow this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)

Use the `GetType()` method to know the data type in C#. You can learn about it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634079/how-can-i-get-the-data-type-of-a-variable-in-c)

Comment: Doing `Random random = new Random();` on every method call is horrible, because if you call the method in fast succesion, you will get the same "random" result. Use *one* (Thread)static instance of `Random` declared somewhere outside the methods to circumvent that problem. See also thoughts about `Random` from [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness/) and [Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2019/01/31/fixing-random-part-1/).